# How to position an ':after' pseudo-element at end of its owner?

Tags: html, css

I would like to get result something like this:
◄ ███████ ►

Is it possible to make arrows with pseudo-elements `:before` and `:after`?

[JSFiddle example which demonstrates the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/j08L8a3b/)

```
<div class="scroll"></div>

.scroll {
  width: 100px;
}
.scroll::before {
  content: "◀";
}

.scroll::after {
  content: "▶";
}
```

Comment: Not sure what your intent is, but just be aware you can't attach javascript events to pseudo elements.  Might be important to you.

Comment: thank you but it's not a problem in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is.

```css
.scroll {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 0 1.2em;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  min-height: 1.2em;
}

.scroll:before,
.scroll:after {
  position: absolute;
  color: grey;
  min-height: 1.2em;
  width: 1.2em;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  line-height: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
}

.scroll:before {
  content: "◀";
  right:100%;
}

.scroll:after {
  content: "▶";
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll"></div>
```

---

Update. Following discussion in chat, here's how I'd style [custom scrollbars](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/oh9b3zLu/1/) on a div. Please note that as of now they are just painted, the `div` changes size based on content. I know nothing about the logic behind your need to paint scrollbars instead of trusting browsers with it. :)

Comment: Thank you, Andrei. Nice solution. I don't know how I could forget about float.. :-( What can you advise regarding ':after' pseudo-element in case vertical div (scroll)?

Comment: The real problem is actually fine controlling the position of the arrow. I personally would not use a "normal" font, but an icons font, to make sure the arrows are exactly in the middle of my containers when i set the width and height equal. For vertical I would still use top and bottom margins equal to the bar's width and place some up and down icons in those, absolutely positioned to my "relative" parent (the bar).

Comment: Alexander, I'd like to thank you for your comment and subsequent question. Had you not have asked this, I would have never given it thought. Now, that you have, I tried various solutions for a custom scroll-bar. My final answer is: I would definitely use **flex-box model**, even if I'd have to add extra CSS for IE below 9, (using box-model). I haven't finished it yet, but I'll update my answer with a link to the fiddle as soon as I will. Not within a few hours though, I really need to tend to something else right now. Happy Holidays!

Comment: I'll take that back. It seemed logic and easy to do with flexbox, but it wasn't such a good idea. Added fiddle.

Comment: Thank you for your research. It's really great! Fortunately, in my case the page will be displayed only in Chrome. Therefore vertical scrollbar I made with flexbox. But your example is really cognitive

Comment: You're welcome. Please note that, while neat and less bloated, the CSS in fiddle is not optimised. For example, `[class^="scrll"] ` is sensibly slower than `.scrllX,.scrllY`.

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of a hack but it works. It involves setting margins.

Here is the updated fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/j08L8a3b/1/

```
.scroll {
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: grey;
}
.scroll::before {
  content: "◀";
  color: grey;
  margin-left: -20px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.scroll::after {
  content: "▶";
  margin-left: 120px;
  color: grey;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But in reality, there is an additional conditional: the width of div.scroll is relative. Also you shift the content of pseudo-elements on the fixed size. It's not very good because the size of font can be changed